# Armature deforming mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I'm trying to learn animation and I'm making an animated lamp but the mesh is deforming even with the deform tickbox unticked. What might be causing this?

The base is a child of stem bone, arm is a child of arm bone, head is child of head bone. The deform tickbox is unticked for each individual bone.

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your question you have different objects for the parts and parented them to the bones. So they are not deformed at all anyways. You have to make one model and parent that to the armature (not a bone) with automatic weights, then that option would probably work but I actually never used it

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it has the same problem. It is deforming the mesh of the lamp head.

Comment: isn't that what it is supposed to do?

Comment: No it's meant to move the head not deform and misshape it.

Comment: is it undeformed if its in Rest Pose? I am sure its nothing in the deform section but in the Modifier Tab. Try enabling preserve Volume. If you want to reset your Pose use Alt+R, Alt+S and maybe also Alt+G in Pose Mode. The Rest Pose is defined in Editmode of the Armature